# Returning a struct from a function in Windows corrupts its data

Tags: c, visual-studio

I have the following C struct used to report the result of a trace in a 2D game.

```
typedef struct TraceResult
{
    bool collided;
    bool beganColliding;
    bool endedColliding;    // If the trace ended while still inside a collider
    float fraction;
    Vector2 endPosition;
    Vector2 contactNormal;
    struct Entity* collisionEnt;
    ComponentType collisionComponentType;
} TraceResult;
```

The struct is being initialised like so:

```
TraceResult workingResult = TraceRectangleMovementAgainstTerrain(
    hull,
    delta,
    Entity_GetTerrainComponent(ent),
    collisionMask
);
```

After I've made this call, the struct is passed back up to the caller of the previous function. I've put a `printf` right before the return statement, and it reports that the contact normal is as expected:

```
printf("Contact normal before returning: (%.2f, %.2f)\n", workingResult.contactNormal.x, workingResult.contactNormal.y);
return workingResult;
```

```
Contact normal before returning: (0.00, -1.00)
```

However, immediately after the function call that the struct is returned from, I have another `printf` statement. This reports that the contact normal is different - it seems to have taken on the value of the `endPosition` member before it:

```
printf("Contact normal after returning: (%.2f, %.2f)\n", result.contactNormal.x, result.contactNormal.y);
```

```
Contact normal after returning: (995.00, 150.00)
```

This issue does not happen when I run the application on Ubuntu, only on Windows. Sometimes returning a `TraceResult` by copy is fine, but other times the values seem to get corrupted like this. Am I going mad, or is the compiler not playing ball here?

Comment: Don't describe your code but show it. You need to show a [mcve]

Comment: Can you spot the differences of the assembly produced by the compiler? Doing a [mre] will help you also in narrowing down the amount of assembly to look at.

Comment: Do calling and called function "see" the same definition of that struct? Using inconsistent types (maybe due to not re-compiling a file after headers change) can cause weird effects.

Comment: Sometimes this happens if you change the struct and for some reason the compiler doesn't recompile all the functions that use it. You can try rebuilding the whole project in Visual Studio - right-click the solution in the explorer -> "Rebuild Solution"

Comment: Sounds like you are returning pointers to local variables or some such. Post the functions and variable declarations.

Comment: @Gerhardh Your comment definitely pointed me in the right direction. It turns out I was using `bool` members in the struct, but had not included `stdbool.h` in the same header as the struct. It still compiled because `stdbool.h` was included somewhere else, but apparently it confused MSVC when it tried to calculate the member offsets. I expect the size or padding surrounding the booleans was different based on whether `bool` was defined at the time the compiler encountered the struct definition.

Comment: That sounds a bit strange. Unless you provide different headers with different definitions of `bool` the result should be the same. But as I read it, you have solved the issue now, correct?

Comment: Yeah, it was very weird. I have solved the issue as far as I can see, but I'd like to do a little investigating this evening to see if I can probe deeper into why it happened, and then present the info as an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 2):

I eventually solved this: the issue was that I had neglected to add `#include <stdbool.h>` to the header where the struct was defined. Once I added this, everything started working as expected.

I was initially confused as to why this was the case - surely if there was no definition of `bool`, the compiler should have thrown an error? However, after a bit of searching I found this in one of my third party library headers:

```
#if defined(__STDC__) && __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
    #include <stdbool.h>
#elif !defined(__cplusplus) && !defined(bool)
    typedef enum bool { false, true } bool;
    #define RL_BOOL_TYPE
#endif
```

According to a quick Google, [MSVC only defines `__STDC__` if the /Za compile option is used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=msvc-170#standard-predefined-macros). Since I didn't have this switched on, the library header used its own type for `bool`, and as this is an enum, it was 4 bytes large instead of 1. This caused confusion regarding struct member offsets depending on whether a compilation units could see `stdbool.h` or not by the time it encountered the definition of the struct.

I'm going to do a few things here to fix this issue for myself:

1. I'm going to set a proper C standard in my CMake project (my bad).
2. I have a header which wraps this library header, because I define a few extra things for it to use. I'm going to add `stdbool.h` to this header just in case.
3. I'm going to submit a PR to the library tighten up the `#ifdef` check. Apparently MSVC supports C99 from VS2013 onwards, so the check could be upgraded to include `stdbool.h` if `_MSC_VER` is defined and is at least `1800`

Comment: Nice investigation. Then you also need to clarify if that 3rd party library was compiled using that `/Za` flag or not, to avoid more surprises

Comment: I built the library as part of my project, so it was compiled with the same settings as I was using.